# asp.net mvc page lifecycle event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Currently we are migrating an existing asp.net web application to asp.net mvc 2 platform. All of our pages performs some business functionality before loading the page or initializing the page. How to achieve this similar behavior in asp.net mvc

The logic which we have currently in pagebase class for web app like this..
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
// Presenter.PerformStartUp()

Please help.

Thanks
Subu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is a totally different pattern than what you might have been used in classic WebForms. There are no events in MVC. The are no pages in MVC. There is notion of PostBack in MVC. There is no ViewState in MVC. There are no server side controls in MVC.

In MVC you have a Controller which receives the user request, it manipulates the Model and passes a view model to the View for displaying. A good starting point is here: http://asp.net/mvc

If the existing application you are trying to migrate has been written properly and it has a service layer and a data access layer at best you could reuse those parts into the new ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net mvc you create ActionResult methods by decorating them with the attribute [HttpPost] and [HttpGet](HttpGet is default) this is what sepparates between a Get and Post.

Comment: thanks. but the if the user presses F5 (refresh) we dont want to call the startup logic

Comment: I don't know what is in the startup logic but in mvc there is no viewstate, so if the user were to press f5 you would still need to handle the get since it won't "remember" what happened before, I'm certain that there is a way to do what you are asking but for me it would revolve in storing what the user did before and if he happens to do the same thing twice abort the second try.

Comment: we have pre-screen logic (on navigating to this page) and when user leaves the page we trigger post-screen logic.how can we hook up these kind of custom logic in the pipeline in generic fashion for all pages